# Strange title corruption of activity when using ListView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, listview

I've got a class (let's call it MyWidget for now) that extends View in which I do some custom drawing in onDraw().  MyWidget works just fine in most situations, except when either adding MyWidget to a ListView or a ScrollView within a TabView.  When in one of these configurations, I consistently observe that scrolling will occasionally overwrite the title area of the View with a partial image of the contents of one of the instances of MyWidget.

I know this is a really confusing description of the problem so Here's a screenshot of the corruption:

[screen corruption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dASM1.jpg)

Any ideas?!

Addition: clipping logic that I use:

```
try {
        canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        // do some clipping here
    } finally {
        canvas.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your View's custom drawing code is doing tricks with the clip rect and you are not properly saving/restoring the Canvas state.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having a hard time finding any clip errors. I added the basic clipping logic that I use anywhere I clip in my code.  Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the problem may have been caused by using Region.Op.REPLACE - my guess is that the ListView uses the public clip to mask up the upper area and REPLACE clobbers it.  In any case I was able to switch to INTERSECT and things seem to be ok.   I'll be accepting your solution after I've verified the problem is indeed gone.  Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly it, if you use REPLACE you must make sure you correctly put the clip back to what is was before you did the REPLACE.

Comment: I actually was restoring the clip to its original state.  I'm thinking its likely -never- safe to use REPLACE with a ListView because any drawable elements that are supposed to be obscured by the title area will just clobber that clip mask and draw up there anyway.  Replacing the clip back to what it was after you are done drawing won't help.

Comment: Well the drawables don't clobber the clip, they usually intersect with the current clip and do save/restore. It's just that by doing a REPLACE you allow them to draw outside of the View's bounds. I'm glad you figured it out though.